# Excel cell value as string won't store as string

Tags: vba, excel

I can’t get this code here to grab cell content and store as string. I get a double:
`54.6666666667` instead of `N03:DM:` (example cell contents).

If I use `Cstr(Sheet1.Cells(i, 5).Value)` I still get same result.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub GetAddress()

Dim varAdd As String
Dim i As Integer

    For i = 2 To 327
        If varTag = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value Then
           varAdd = Sheet1.Cells(i, 5).Value
           varAdd = Left(varAdd, 7)
           Sheet3.Cells(incR, 2).Value = varAdd
           Exit For
        End If   
    Next i

End Sub
```

Sheet screenshot [image]

Comment: Can you provide screenshot of sheet1.

Comment: @Santosh posted screenshot, thanks.

Comment: Do you have multiple workbook open ? `msgbox Sheet1.Parent.name` will let  you know the name of workbook? I hope data is in sheet1.

Comment: @Santosh only displays name of workbook. Yes, data is in sheet1. Looks like mehow provided a solution that works. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you upload your workbook and give me the link. Want to understand why the text work and value does not. Tks.

Comment: @santosh wish I could but I have no way to do that right now. StackOverflow doesn't have this feature right?

Comment: you can upload on skydrive or similar sites.

Comment: @santosh I wish I could help you understand why value did not work and text does as I"m curious myself. I don't have account to skydrive or anything similar. Sorry and thanks for your help.

Comment: @Santosh No thanks, appreciate your help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use `Range("A1").Text` instead of `.Value`

post comment edit:
Why?
Because the `.Text` property of Range object returns what is literally visible in the spreadsheet, so if you cell displays for example `i100l:25he*_92` then <- `Text` will return exactly what it in the cell including any formatting. 
The `.Value` and `.Value2` properties return what's stored in the cell **under the hood** excluding formatting. Specially `.Value2` for date types, it will return the decimal representation.

If you want to dig deeper into the meaning and performance, I just found [`this article`](http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/) which seems like a good guide

**another edit**
Here you go @Santosh
type in (**MANUALLY**) the values from the **DEFAULT** (col A) to other columns
Do not format column A at all
Format column B as Text
Format column C as Date[dd/mm/yyyy]
Format column D as Percentage
[image: Dont Format column A, Format B as TEXT, C as Date, D as Percentage]
now, 
paste this code in a module

```
Sub main()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, i&, j&
    Set ws = Sheets(1)
    For i = 3 To 7
        For j = 1 To 4
            Debug.Print _
                    "row " & i & vbTab & vbTab & _
                    Cells(i, j).Text & vbTab & _
                    Cells(i, j).Value & vbTab & _
                    Cells(i, j).Value2
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

and **`Analyse`** the output! Its really easy and there isn't much more i can do to help :)

```
            .TEXT              .VALUE             .VALUE2
row 3       hello             hello               hello
row 3       hello             hello               hello
row 3       hello             hello               hello
row 3       hello             hello               hello
row 4       1                 1                   1
row 4       1                 1                   1
row 4       01/01/1900        31/12/1899          1
row 4       1.00%             0.01                0.01
row 5       helo1$$           helo1$$             helo1$$
row 5       helo1$$           helo1$$             helo1$$
row 5       helo1$$           helo1$$             helo1$$
row 5       helo1$$           helo1$$             helo1$$
row 6       63                63                  63
row 6       =7*9              =7*9                =7*9
row 6       03/03/1900        03/03/1900          63
row 6       6300.00%          63                  63
row 7       29/05/2013        29/05/2013          41423
row 7       29/05/2013        29/05/2013          29/05/2013
row 7       29/05/2013        29/05/2013          41423
row 7       29/05/2013%       29/05/2013%         29/05/2013%
```