# Excel Interlop Value vs Text vs Value2

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

Having some problems parsing numbers out of the following excel spread sheet.

[image: Excel]

**The code:**

```
  var curQOH = toolkit.ExcelWorksheet.Cells[i, 28] as Range;
                        var curQAV = toolkit.ExcelWorksheet.Cells[i, 29] as Range;
                        if (!curQOH.Text.Contains("("))
                            Int32.TryParse(curQOH.Text, out lastQOH);
                        else
                            Int32.TryParse(curQOH.Value as string, out lastQOH);
                        if (!curQAV.Text.Contains("("))
                            Int32.TryParse(curQAV.Text, out lastQAV);
                        else
                            Int32.TryParse(curQAV.Value as string, out lastQAV);
```

The code above parses the positive numbers just fine. No issues. But it seems like it cannot parse negative number.

To my knowledge, Text is suppose to give me what the viewer sees so I would get (10) as an output. Value does give the right number but I cannot seem to parse that after casting to string. (this issue why I cant store the value as string or cast it to int, [Excel cell value as string won't store as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16820553/excel-cell-value-as-string-wont-store-as-string))

Comment: I would recommend using the EPPlus open source library rather than Interop.  It's much nicer to use.

Comment: I've always used `Value2` which I will then convert to `string` to parse. But (if I'm reading your code correctly) you'll be attempting to parse `@"(10)"` to an `int` which will fail.

Comment: @StephenRoss I am checking if it has ( character is so then I am doing value which should give -10 and then I am parsing to int.

Comment: @DarrenYoung Can't it's an xls not xlsx

Comment: How is that cell formatted in the worksheet? Trying `(10)` in the worksheet and `.Value` gives me `@"(10)"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stoped using Excel Interlop and started using OpenXML Excel library